# Calculate the sum between two iterators in STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am working on a problem in STL containers:

**Create a Sum() function that calculates the sum between two iterators. The function then uses the template argument for the iterator type and accepts two iterators, the start and the end**

I am trying to write the following code but I am not understanding the problem can anyone help me please .

```
template <typename type , typename start , typename  end>
double sum(type& t, start& s , end& e) 
{
  typename t::const_iterator i;
  double sum = 0;
  for (i = s  ; i != e; ++i)
    {
      sum+=*i;
    }
  return sum;
}


int main()
{
  //for list 
  list<double> l; //creat a double type list
  l.push_back(10); //pushing data into list l
  l.push_front(11);//pushing data into list l
  l.push_back(9);//pushing data into list l
  l.push_front(12);//pushing data into list l
  l.push_back(8);//pushing data into list l
  list<double>::iterator itlist;

   cout<<"Sum of List L is : "<< sum( itlist , l.begin() , l.end())<<endl;
}
```

I don't think i am doing correct. i have got many errors. one of my error is:

```
no instance of overloaded function "sum" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::_List_iterator<double>, std::_List_iterator<double>, std::_List_iterator<double>)
```

Comment: You haven't told us what problem you're facing. Add that to the question please.

Comment: What is `t` please?

Comment: the code is not compiling, as it is giving many errors. i don't think i am working correctly .

Comment: no instance of overloaded function "sum" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::_List_iterator<double>, std::_List_iterator<double>, std::_List_iterator<double>)

Comment: Thanks. Can you add that to the question, instead of as a comment?

Comment: `t` is a variable, not a type or namespace. `t::const_iterator` doesn't make sense.

Comment: so, can i change this to  typename type::const_iterator i ?

Comment: `sum` takes parameters by non-const reference, which means corresponding arguments can't be temporaries. Whereas `l.begin()` and `l.end()` return temporaries. Typically, you would take iterators by value, not by reference (`const` or otherwise).

Comment: See template parameters, between < and >. You have three of them but provided only one <double>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. In this function:

```
template <typename type , typename start , typename  end>
double sum(type& t, start& s , end& e)
```

you are taking `s` and `e` by reference. But this can't bind to `l.begin()` or `l.end()`, since they return r-values.

Iterators are generally passed around by copy anyway, so you can simply write:

```
template <typename type , typename start , typename  end>
double sum(type& t, start s , end e)
```

---

You also have an issue here:

```
typename t::const_iterator i;
```

You can't do this because `t` is a variable, not a type.

However, you don't need to spell out the type of `i` at all. Instead, you could simply write:

```
for (auto i = s  ; i != e; ++i)
{
  // ...
}
```

and let the compiler deduce the type of `i`.

---

In fact, there is no need to pass `itlist` to your function at all, since all the needed information is in the other arguments. Also, since both arguments have the same type, you only need one template parameter.

So now your function would simply be

```
template <typename iter>    // a single template argument
double sum(iter s , iter e) // 2 function arguments, both of the same type
{
  // ...
}
```

and you would call it like this:

```
sum(l.begin() , l.end())
```

---

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kh7v36).

Comment: yes the errors are gone thanks for the answering but can you explain me what is the purpose of t then ? where i have to use iterator type ?

Comment: @HamzaAsif There's no purpose to `t`. I've edited the answer to explain that.

Comment: I think your answer is better than mine, nice!

Comment: Thank you for the answer  i can understand the now, thanks for the demo . the code is running fine and giving me proper output

Comment: @HamzaAsif It seems you're trying to accept multiple answers. But you can only choose at most one. You can upvote all the answers you find useful though :)

Comment: @gsamaras if you see my problem : this line : The function then uses the template argument for the iterator type and accepts two iterators .. what i have to do with this ?? should i ignore this ? please help and thanks for the answer i can understand very well thank you soo much

Comment: @HamzaAsif No problem :) Glad to see you're learning how to participate. And yes, you only need a single *template argument* because both the *function arguments* have the same type. I've edited my answer, and demo, to show that.

Comment: okay, Thank you for your time. The code is now working perfectly fine. Thanks for the demo now, i understand all the code .

Comment: And, for completeness, in the final code that loop can be written without `auto` and without a separate typedef for the iterator type. The type of the iterator is easy enough to write: `for (iter i = s; i != e; ++i) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could try is to pass const references to start and end of the iterators. Moreover, just one typename is enough, you can discard the others.

Then this `typename t::const_iterator i;` doesn't  make sense, because `t` is a variable. To answer your comment, you cannot do `typename type::const_iterator i;` either.

Easiest solution would be to discard that problematic line of the const iterator, and use the `auto` keyword in the for loop.

Putting everything together, you get this:

```
template <typename T>
double sum(T const& start, T const& end) 
{
  double sum = 0;
  for(auto i = start; i != end; ++i)
  {
    sum+=*i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

which is called like this:

```
cout << "Sum of List L is: "<< sum(l.begin() , l.end()) << endl;
```

and outputs (<kbd>[Run it Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U9wnSleAyLg2jFCs)</kbd>):

```
Sum of List L is: 50
```

---

Alternative: @cigien's answer, which passes the iterators by value instead of reference, which is the typical method of passing iterators - I was just trying to stick as close as possible to OP's code.

---

To answer your comment:

> Create a Sum() function that calculates the sum between two iterators.
> The function then uses the template argument **for the iterator type**
> and accepts two iterators, the start and the end.

Then you could simply use the typename `T` instead of the `auto` keyword, like this:

```
template <typename T>
double sum(T const& start,T const& end) 
{
  double sum = 0;
  for(T i = start; i != end; ++i)
  {
    sum+=*i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

<kbd>[Run it Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fvSR9MUyQ2NWmPgH)</kbd>

Comment: if you see my problem : this line : The function then uses the template argument for the iterator type and accepts two iterators .. what i have to do with this ?? should i ignore this ? please help and thanks for the answer i can understand very well thank you soo much

Comment: This : line :? @HamzaAsif what do you mean please? You are welcome.

Comment: please see my problem in the post =>  Create a Sum() function that calculates the sum between two iterators. **The function then uses the template argument for the iterator type and accepts two iterators**, the start and the end

Comment: @HamzaAsif I understand, if you want to do it exactly like that, then use the typename `T` instead of the `auto` keyword, like my edited answers explains at its end. Hope that helps, welcome to Stack Overflow! :)